# R ggvis multiple lines from different dataframes

Tags: r, ggvis

I have the following data:

```
tmp1 = data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(1,3,10))
tmp2 = data.frame(x=seq(0,4,.1),y=seq(0,4,.1)^2)
```

And I would like to make a plot with dots from tmp1 and line from tmp2. I am trying:

```
ggvis(data=tmp1,x=~x,y=~y) %>% layer_points() %>% layer_lines(data=tmp2,x=~x,y=~y)
```

Is there someone who knows how to make this code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
ggvis(data=tmp2, x=~x, y=~y) %>% 
  layer_lines() %>% 
  layer_points(data=tmp1, x=~x, y=~y)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see I was really close but never thought it would matter if I put layer_points or layer_lines first!